# How to select one table column using user define function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Create one user define function  with some default inputs and return table.
the below function result used to another function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Splittext(@strArgs VARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS @tab TABLE
(
    [Key] VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Value VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @tab VALUES('Key1', 'Value1')
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES('Key2', 'Value2')

RETURN
END
GO

select * from dbo.Splittext('test') run this funtion output like 

Key Value
*************
Key1    Value1
Key2    Value2
```

---

The  below function return only the varchar from selected table.

```
       CREATE FUNCTION dbo.slecttext()
RETURNs   varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @value varchar(20)
DECLARE @Table Table (keyss varchar(20), valuess varchar(20))

select  @Table  = value from dbo.Splittext('test') 

select @value  = Keyys from @Table 
 Return @value 

END
GO

    select * from  dbo.slecttext() - when i run this function
```

I need Output Like

```
keyss 
********
Key1    
Key2
```

if possible this case..

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but in the second udf you are trying to assign the result into a table variable. The easier method would be:

```
DECLARE @Table Table (keyss varchar(20), valuess varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT  * FROM dbo.Splittext('test')
SELECT keyss FROM @Table
```

Thanks,